# Getting error Ajv is not a constructor while building react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

Even after downgraded the `mini-css-extract-plugin` version via  `npm i -D --save-exact mini-css-extract-plugin@2.4.5` I am getting the below error. How can I resolve this error, I have provided my package.json version list as below. Could someone please advise the issue here.

// Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "sssclub",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.8.3",
    "@mui/material": "^5.8.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.4",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tweet-embed": "^2.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.20.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.14.2",
    "npm": "8.5.0"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:server": "node src/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.4.5"
  }
}
```

// Error details below:

```
2022-06-13T21:08:42.677828+00:00 app[web.1]: > sssclub@0.1.0 start
2022-06-13T21:08:42.677828+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2022-06-13T21:08:42.677828+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328689+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:66
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328698+00:00 app[web.1]: const ajv = new Ajv({
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328699+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328699+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328700+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Ajv is not a constructor
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328701+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:66:13)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328702+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328703+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328703+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328703+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328704+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328704+00:00 app[web.1]: at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328704+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/index.js:6:5)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328705+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.328705+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
2022-06-13T21:08:43.509101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-13T21:08:43.439898+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

Comment: I am getting a run time issue in Heroku, but not in my local system.

Comment: Any advise to solve the issue, as Heroku will not help with run time issue